# Opening a Socket to get input stream from a(https server) web url on click of button

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-videoview

I was trying open a socket connection on click of button. When the socket connection  is successful i have to get the web url data which is in https server.Finally i need to pass the received data to Video View for playing.
Got stucked with the following error everytime:

```
     **java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host <url>: No address associated with hostname**
```

Below is my code to open socket.

```
private void openSocket() {

    Runnable serverTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Socket s = new Socket("http://www.zocdoc.com/", 80);

                //outgoing stream redirect to socket
                OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();

                PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);
                output.println("Hello Android!");
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

                //read line(s)
                String st = input.readLine();

                Log.d(TAG, "openSocket: " + st);
                //Close connection
                s.close();


            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Thread serverThread = new Thread(serverTask);
    serverThread.start();
}
```

I have checked my internet connection and its fine.Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new Socket("http://www.zocdoc.com/", 80);
```

The problem is in the first argument: you must specify there host name and not an HTTP URL. Try the following, if you want to open a TCP socket:

```
new Socket("www.zocdoc.com", 80);
```

But if you want to consume a stream of data from that http url, `Socket` is not what you need (if you are not willing to implement HTTP protocol yourself). You could use something like the following with vanilla `URL` API:

```
InputStream is = new URL("http://www.zocdoc.com/").openStream();
// read from that stream
```

Or use some HTTP client like Apache Httpcomponents http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/

Comment: Thank you so much..Am not getting that exception now.But getting null from input stream.

Comment: I've extended the answer